# How to apply range() on subsequent elements of a list

Tags: python

I want to find range of numbers between `ith`, `ith + 1` elements of a list, for example, given a list `[1, 3, 5, 7]`, I want to return `range(1,3), range(3,5), range(5, 7)`. Is there a better way to doing this?
See my code below, it works but I want to assume its not efficient because each loop check if its the last item in the list, any better way to do this?

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
itemList = df['A'].values.tolist()

for idx, value in enumerate(itemList):
    if itemList[idx]!= itemList[-1]:
        print range(value, itemList[idx + 1])
```

Comment: `[range(*x) for x in zip(lst, lst[1:])]`

Comment: An alternative way to do the unpacking of the `range` args: `[range(start, stop) for start, stop in zip(lst, lst[1:])]`. True, it's not as compact, but it's a little more explicit. :)